# how to make foundation 5 compatible for all IE versions >=8

Tags: html, css, media-queries, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I want to make my site compatible for all versions of ie greater than 7. Can anyone kindly guide me to do this??
I included below js files but still its not working

Comment: It's explained [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/learn/faq.html) You have to use Foundation 4 for < IE8 support

Comment: thankyou for your reply general03 but i m using foundation 5...I followed the below link [link](http://www.kycosoftware.com/blog/article/getting-foundation-5-to-work-in-ie8). It causes positive results but not appreciable ...even the slider is not working in all ie versions

Comment: What does not work ? Have you javascript errors ?

Comment: media query and css is not working in ie. Some divs and images are not aligned properly ...and the slider images are down to each other.

Comment: Look at this [forum](https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/), the [css3-mediaqueries-js](https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/) may help you

Comment: Thank you general03 but the link is unavailable :(

Comment: Sorry, this is this [post link](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/241-foundation-5-and-ie8)

Comment: Thank you general03 for your information :). media query issue has been fixed

Answer (score 0):

Foundation 5 [doesn't support IE 8](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/compatibility.html) at all but you can try [this](http://www.kycosoftware.com/blog/article/getting-foundation-5-to-work-in-ie8).

Quoted from [Foundation FAQ](http://foundation.zurb.com/learn/faq.html):

> **Why doesn't Foundation support IE7 or IE8? Or: why we don't support a dying species.**
>
> This is probably the biggest question we get. Consider this: most of
>   today's popular browsers automatically upgrade themselves including
>   Chrome, Firefox and Explorer (starting with 9). IE 8 is the last IE
>   supported on Windows XP, which Microsoft will officially stop
>   supporting next year. That played a part in our decision.
>
> Besides that, since Foundation 4, our framework is built mobile-first,
>   meaning it relies on media queries to layer in more complex layouts
>   and components. Browsers or devices that don't support media queries
>   will be restricted to a simple, single-column layout. In some ways,
>   Foundation 4 better supports IE6-7 insomuch as it provides a mobile
>   but not entirely broken experience. If IE8 support is important for
>   your users / customers, you can use Foundation 3.2, which supports
>   IE8. It's not mobile first but it's good stuff.